# Whole component re renders when modal opens in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <GlobalStyle />
          {componentName !== 'questionaire' &&
            componentName !== 'activityResult' && <CardWrapper />}

          <ErrorModal
            errorModal={errorModal}
            handleErrorModal={handleError}
            errorMsg={error}
          />
          {successModal && successMsg  ? (
            <SuccessModal successModal={successModal} successMsg={successMsg} />
          ) : (
            <Grid
              className="card-layout"
              style={
                componentName === 'questionaire'
                  ? { margin: '20px', height: 'calc(100% - 40px)' }
                  : { margin: '30px 20px' }
              }
            >
              {customTagProps.meterId && (
                <CustomTag type={componentName} propData={customTagProps} />
              )}
            </Grid>
          )}
        </ThemeProvider>
```

I have a modal component, which on load re renders the entire component. I want to prevent the re render of the entire component.

Answer (score 0):

lack of Information

may I only suggest you try using useRef instead of useState

you could use useMemo() to return the component